# npm run dev doesn't do any pulling - laravel

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm trying to see why npm run dev doesn't seem to be pulling in anything. When I put "npm run dev" I get:

```
> dev
> npm run development
```

That is it.

I am running tailwind with laravel, and only have a basic understanding of what npm run dev does, but I think it should be outputting a lot more, expecially when trying to add tailwind info.

My webpack.mis.js file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss')
    ]);
```

app.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: what's in your webpack.mix.js file?

Comment: what do you mean with "pulling in anything"

Comment: I added in my webpack.mix.js file. By "pulling in anything" from the tutorial I am following, it should output more, and my app.css file should be changed.